# Uploading video to Twitter sometimes doesn't work

Tags: laravel, api, twitter, ffmpeg

I have a very difficult situation. I've already spent 2 days and couldn't find a solution. Project on Laravel. I want to upload videos to Twitter using the Twitter API endpoints. But sometimes I am getting this error:

> file is currently unsupported

I did everything as recommended in the official documentation [Video specifications and recommendations](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices). I get an error when I set an audio codec is **aac** in my video file, despite the fact that it is recommended in the official documentation, but when I set the audio codec to **mp3**, the video is uploaded, but the sound quality is very poor, and sometimes there is no sound at all. Please forgive me if this is awkward to read, but I want to provide all of my code. Because I don't know how to solve this anymore and I think it might help.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\PublishedContent;
use Atymic\Twitter\Facades\Twitter;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class PublishToTwitter implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $publishingData;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param $publishingData
     */
    public function __construct($publishingData)
    {
        $this->publishingData = $publishingData;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $publishingData = $this->publishingData;

        if (is_array($publishingData)) {
            $publishingResult = $this->publishing(...array_values($publishingData));
            sendNotification($publishingResult['message'], $publishingResult['status'], 'Twitter', $publishingResult['link'], $publishingData['post_name'], $publishingData['user']);
        } else {
            $scheduledData = processingScheduledPost($publishingData);
            $postName = $scheduledData['scheduleData']['post_name'];
            $postContent = $scheduledData['scheduleData']['post_content'];
            $userToken = json_decode($publishingData->user_token,true);
            $requestToken = [
                'token'  => $userToken['oauth_token'],
                'secret' => $userToken['oauth_token_secret'],
            ];
            $publishingResult = $this->publishing($scheduledData['file'], $postName, $postContent, $requestToken);
            $publishingResult['status'] && PublishedContent::add($scheduledData['craft'], $scheduledData['file'], "twitter_share");
            sendResultToUser($publishingData, $scheduledData['user'], $publishingResult['message'], $postName, $publishingResult['link'], $publishingResult['publishing_status'], $scheduledData['social_media']);
            sendNotification($publishingResult['message'], $publishingResult['status'], 'Twitter', $publishingResult['link'], $postName, $scheduledData['user']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $file
     * @param $postName
     * @param $postContent
     * @param $requestToken
     * @return array
     */
    private function publishing($file, $postName, $postContent, $requestToken): array
    {
        $result = [
            'status' => false,
            'link' => null,
            'message' => 'Your content can\'t successfully published on Twitter. This file is not supported for publishing.',
            'publishing_status' => 'error'
        ];

        if ((($file->refe_type !== 'text') || $file->refe_file_path) && !checkIfFileExist($file->refe_file_path)) {
            $result['message'] = 'Missing or invalid file.';
            return $result;
        }

        $filePath = $file->refe_file_path;
        $fileSize = $file->content_length;
        $tempFileName = 'temp-' . $file->refe_file_name;
        $ext = $file->file_type;
        $mediaCategory = 'tweet_' . $file->refe_type;
        $mediaType = $file->refe_type . '/' . $ext;
        $remoteFile = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $tempFolder = public_path('/storage/uploads/temp');

        if (!file_exists($tempFolder)) {
            mkdir($tempFolder, 0777, true);
        }

        $tempFile = public_path('/storage/uploads/temp/' . $tempFileName);
        File::put($tempFile, $remoteFile);
        $convertedFileName = 'converted-' . $file->refe_file_name;
        $convertedFile = public_path('/storage/uploads/temp/' . $convertedFileName);
        $command = 'ffmpeg -y -i '.$tempFile.' -b:v 5000k -b:a 380k -c:a aac -profile:a aac_low -threads 1 '.$convertedFile.'';
        exec($command);
        @File::delete($tempFile);

        try {
            $twitter = Twitter::usingCredentials($requestToken['token'], $requestToken['secret']);
            if ($file->refe_type === 'text') {
                $twitter->postTweet([
                    'status' => urldecode($postContent),
                    'format' => 'json',
                ]);

                $result['link'] = 'https://twitter.com/home';
                $result['status'] = true;
                $result['message'] = 'Your content successfully published on Twitter. You can visit to Twitter and check it.';
                $result['publishing_status'] = 'done';
            } else if ($file->refe_type === 'video' || $file->refe_type === 'image') {
                if ($file->refe_type === 'video') {
                    $duration = getVideoDuration($file->refe_file_path);

                    if ($duration > config('constant.sharing_configs.max_video_duration.twitter')) {
                        throw new \Exception('The duration of the video file must not exceed 140 seconds.');
                    }
                }

                $isFileTypeSupported = checkPublishedFileType('twitter', $file->refe_type, strtolower($ext));
                $isFileSizeSupported = checkPublishedFileSize('twitter', $file->refe_type, $fileSize, strtolower($ext));

                if (!$isFileTypeSupported) {
                    throw new \Exception('Your content can\'t successfully published on Twitter. This file type is not supported for publishing.');
                }

                if (!$isFileSizeSupported) {
                    throw new \Exception('Your content can\'t successfully published on Twitter. The file size is exceeded.');
                }

                if ($file->refe_type === 'video') $fileSize = filesize($convertedFile);

                if (strtolower($ext) === 'gif') {
                    $initMedia = $twitter->uploadMedia([
                        'command' => 'INIT',
                        'total_bytes' => (int)$fileSize
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $initMedia = $twitter->uploadMedia([
                        'command' => 'INIT',
                        'media_type' => $mediaType,
                        'media_category' => $mediaCategory,
                        'total_bytes' => (int)$fileSize
                    ]);
                }

                $mediaId = (int)$initMedia->media_id_string;

                $fp = fopen($convertedFile, 'r');
                $segmentId = 0;

                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576);

                    $twitter->uploadMedia([
                        'media_data' => base64_encode($chunk),
                        'command' => 'APPEND',
                        'segment_index' => $segmentId,
                        'media_id' => $mediaId
                    ]);

                    $segmentId++;
                }

                fclose($fp);

                $twitter->uploadMedia([
                    'command' => 'FINALIZE',
                    'media_id' => $mediaId
                ]);

                if ($file->refe_type === 'video') {
                    $waits = 0;

                    while ($waits <= 4) {
                        // Authorizing header for Twitter API
                        $oauth = [
                            'command' => 'STATUS',
                            'media_id' => $mediaId,
                            'oauth_consumer_key' => config('twitter.consumer_key'),
                            'oauth_nonce' => Str::random(42),
                            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                            'oauth_token' => $requestToken['token'],
                            'oauth_version' => '1.0'
                        ];

                        // Generate an OAuth 1.0a HMAC-SHA1 signature for an HTTP request
                        $baseInfo = $this->buildBaseString('https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json', 'GET', $oauth);
                        // Getting a signing key
                        $compositeKey = rawurlencode(config('twitter.consumer_secret')) . '&' . rawurlencode($requestToken['secret']);
                        // Calculating the signature
                        $oauthSignature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseInfo, $compositeKey, true));
                        $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauthSignature;
                        $headers['Authorization'] = $this->buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth);

                        try {
                            $guzzle = new GuzzleClient([
                                'headers' => $headers
                            ]);
                            $response = $guzzle->request( 'GET', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=STATUS&media_id=' . $mediaId);
                            $uploadStatus = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
                        } catch (\Exception | GuzzleException $e) {
                            dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getLine(), $e->getFile());
                        }

                        if (isset($uploadStatus->processing_info->state)) {
                            switch ($uploadStatus->processing_info->state) {
                                case 'succeeded':
                                    $waits = 5; // break out of the while loop
                                    break;
                                case 'failed':
                                    File::delete($tempFile);
                                    Log::error('File processing failed: ' . $uploadStatus->processing_info->error->message);
                                    throw new \Exception('File processing failed: ' . $uploadStatus->processing_info->error->message);
                                default:
                                    sleep($uploadStatus->processing_info->check_after_secs);
                                    $waits++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new \Exception('There was an unknown error uploading your file');
                        }
                    }
                }

                $twitter->postTweet(['status' => urldecode($postContent), 'media_ids' => $initMedia->media_id_string]);
                @File::delete($convertedFile);
                $result['link'] = 'https://twitter.com/home';
                $result['status'] = true;
                $result['message'] = 'Your content successfully published on Twitter. You can visit to Twitter and check it.';
                $result['publishing_status'] = 'done';
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
            $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            return $result;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $baseURI
     * @param $method
     * @param $params
     * @return string
     *
     * Creating the signature base string
     */
    protected function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params): string
    {
        $r = array();
        ksort($params);
        foreach($params as $key=>$value){
            $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
        }
        return $method . "&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
    }

    /**
     * @param $oauth
     * @return string
     *
     * Collecting parameters
     */
    protected function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth): string
    {
        $r = 'OAuth ';
        $values = array();
        foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
            $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
        $r .= implode(', ', $values);
        return $r;
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone would help me.

Comment: If it works most of the time but fails sometimes I think the problem is more likely to be related to the file format than to the code. Do you have examples that work and that fail?

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text from `ffmpeg -i input-file-that-does-not-upload.mp4`. It will show informative details about the video that doesn't work.

Comment: did you solve it? I am getting the same error